# OTA midlet issue

Tags: eclipse, java-me, mobile

After installing my midlet to a phone over the air, I'm getting a blank page from browser which need to be closed manually.

1. Any idea how to prevent it?
2. I read that JAD files are no longer required, as the all info located in JAR. I tried to use the JAR files instead of JAD's, but with them the browser first downloads and only then offers to install the middlet. With JAD it offers to install first, which IMHO more user friendly. Is this the expected behavior, or it can be improved and remove the need in JAD's?

I'm using Eclipse MJT (Previously called EclipseME).

Comment: add the jad file and handset model to your question

Answer (score 1):

A JAD file makes it easier to sign and deploy your application.

I would definitely not expect all phones to be able to install an applicaiton from the JAR alone.

Without more information, I can see 2 reasons why a blank web browser page would be left on the screen after a jad install:

- bug in handset firmware. Not only can the phone not download the jar without launching a full web browser but it also forgets to close the browser window. It happens.
- your application asks the phone to notify a remote computer after installation. There is a standard application property for this in the MIDP specifications. it could be in the jad or in the manifest.

Comment: 1) I think the 2nd point is more close to home. any idea how the property is called? And how it can be disabled?

2) I see, so JAD is more widely supported. What about Wap Push? AFAIK it works only with JAR's, so basically JAD is not needed when using Wap Push.